# I installed nativescript but tns command isn't running on mac

Tags: npm, nativescript, node-modules

I installed a native script without a problem. But try to create a new project it can't find tns command.

> nativescript@5.1.0 postinstall
>   /Users/turgut/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/nativescript
>
> > node postinstall.js
>
> Autocompletion is already enabled
>
> Installation successful. You are good to go. Connect with us on
>   http://twitter.com/NativeScript.
>
> You have successfully installed the NativeScript CLI! To create a new
>   project, you use: tns create
>
> To build your project locally you use: tns build
>
> NOTE: Local builds require additional setup of your environment. You
>   can find more information here:
>   https://docs.nativescript.org/start/quick-setup
>
> To build your project in the cloud you can use: tns cloud build
>
> NOTE: Cloud builds require Telerik account. You can find more
>   information here:
>   https://docs.nativescript.org/sidekick/intro/requirements
>
> If you want to experiment with NativeScript in your browser, try the
>   Playground: https://play.nativescript.org
>
> If you have any questions, check Stack Overflow:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nativescript and our public
>   Slack channel: https://nativescriptcommunity.slack.com/
>
> - nativescript@5.1.0 updated 67 packages in 6.648s

By the way, when I first installed it. It can find the command but when I restart the mac this problem pop upped. I already out text it ->

> Installation successful. You are good to go. Connect with us on
>   http://twitter.com/NativeScript.
>
> You have successfully installed the NativeScript CLI! To create a new
>   project, you use: tns create
>
> To build your project locally you use: tns build

what is the problem here?

Comment: Did you solve it? I am facing this issue.

Comment: i couldn't solve it. and then I start writing react native. much more easier.... @Pramod

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `nvm`?

If so, in your terminal, first check whether nativescript has been installed for the version of node you are using:

```
nvm ls
```

You should see an arrow pointing to the current version of Node in use.

Now navigate to `~/.nvm/versions/node/` and select the current version of node you are using. Next, bury down into `lib/node_modules` you should see the `nativescript` folder in here.

If not, you may have installed nativescript to another node version. Check the other versions node_modules further to find out which it was installed to.

Once you've figured this, simply tell nvm to use that version of node:

```
nvm use {version}
```

followed by

```
tns --version
```

to check the install status of nativescript.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the path to your system variables